# Formula / Macro needed for converting rows to columns based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

So here's my dilemma, I'm converting a csv file from one ecommerce store to another, and I need to re-arrange the data. Transpose would work, however I need information to break to a new line after a specified condition changes.

i.e.

product id    imagepath       rank
99999999    /image1.jpg     1
99999999    /image2.jpg     2
99999999    /image3.jpg     3
88888888    /image4.jpg     1

and I need it to be output such as:

product id      imagepath        imagepath2          imagepath3
99999999      /image1.jpg      /image2.jpg          /image3.jpg
88888888      /image4.jpg

So essentially every time the product id changes, I need the information to break to a new line.  the spreadsheet is about 1200 rows or so like this. Some prod ids have 7 images, some have one. I'm sure a FOR LOOP is needed, or something to that degree, but I'm not that well verse in macros to generate it myself, and I can't seem to find a specific example on here... HELP!

Comment: Do you already have the 'rank' column in your worksheet?

Comment: Would rank always go like that (1,2,3,...7) for each product ID?... If so, you could use that and do this as a formula fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried yet? Asking to do it for you? Could you at least provide a code or any progress you made?

```
<Maybe create a new table for your output>
Set ProductValues = ActiveDocument.Fields("product id").GetPossibleValues
For i = 0 To ProductValues.Count - 1
 ActiveDocument.Fields("product id").Select ProductValues.Item(i).Text
 Set imagepath= ActiveDocument.Fields("imagepath").GetPossibleValues
 For j = 0 To imagepath.Count - 1
        ActiveDocument.Fields("imagepath").Select imagepath.Item(i).Text
        Set rank= ActiveDocument.Fields("rank").GetPossibleValues
        For k = 0 To rank.Count - 1
              ActiveDocument.Fields("rank").Select rank.Item(i).Text
              <if the current product_id exists on the export table>
              <copy current row information in new table>
              <if has already a picture, increase the table columns by 1 and add new picture url>
              <or if rank give the amount of picture, you can loop through all rank position at beginning in order to find the maximum rank and intialize your table with [][your rank]>
              <For export table you do mytable[0][0]=product id>
              <check if product id is different from mytable[i-position] and different from product id>
              <to do the picture part mytable[i-position][rank]=picture url>
        Next
  Next
Next
```

This should give you the possibility to go through all your single elements one by one, your task now to finish the rest and to create the new table.